# How to avoid error #NA when executing my macro

Tags: excel, vba, excel-tables, listobject

I have this error with my macro. My macro takes data from a table and in another sheet, outputs in a table my data for each value of a third sheet.

So let's say my table's value are : Jack and Daniel. And on my third sheet, I have Football and Rugby. The output in the second page will be :

```
Jack Football
Jack Rugby
Daniel Football
Daniel Rugby
```

Here is my macro :

```
Sub yo()
Dim Letters, Chk, Ele As Range, i As Long: Letters = Sheets("Sports").Range("C3:C5").Value
For Each Ele In Sheets("Students").ListObjects(1).ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange
    With Sheets("OK").ListObjects(1)
        Chk = Application.Match(Ele, .ListColumns(1).Range, 0)
        If IsError(Chk) Then
            For i = 1 To 3
                .ListRows.Add.Range = Array(Ele, Letters(i, 1))
            Next i
        End If
    End With
Next Ele
End Sub
```

However this works fine. The problem comes from all the other columns of the table in my second sheet. They all get the value "#NA". So instead of having nothing or formulas expanding down, there is that error.

How can I overcome this error ?

Comment: Sort the errors in the table on the second sheet.

Comment: How many columns does your table in worksheet `OK` have?

Comment: @VBasic2008 4 columns

Comment: Not a cause of your error, but VBA needs you to declare the Type for Each variable Separately. As it is, only "Ele" is a Range. Letters and Chk will be Variants because they don't have as "As...". This may be what you intended, but if not it may mask errors. I believe VB.Net allows that "shortcut", but VBA doesn't. [Office VBA Documentation of Dim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dim-statement)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Copy to Excel Table (`ListObject`)

- The short answer is that in this case a ListRow has four columns yet you're assigning it an array of only two. By the looks of your answer, you have concluded this yourself (`.Resize(, 2)`).

**An Improvement**

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub AddStudents()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim wsSports As Worksheet: Set wsSports = wb.Sheets("Sports")
    Dim Sports(): Sports = wsSports.Range("C3:C5").Value
    Dim SportsCount As Long: SportsCount = UBound(Sports, 1)
    
    Dim wsStudents As Worksheet: Set wsStudents = wb.Sheets("Students")
    Dim loStudents As ListObject: Set loStudents = wsStudents.ListObjects(1)
    Dim lcStudents As ListColumn: Set lcStudents = loStudents.ListColumns(1)
    Dim rgStudents As Range: Set rgStudents = lcStudents.DataBodyRange
    
    Dim wsOK As Worksheet: Set wsOK = wb.Sheets("OK")
    Dim loOK As ListObject: Set loOK = wsOK.ListObjects(1)
    Dim lcOK As ListColumn: Set lcOK = loOK.ListColumns(1)
    Dim rgOK As Range: Set rgOK = lcOK.DataBodyRange
    
    Dim cell As Range, Student, MatchOK, r As Long, IsNotStudentAdded As Boolean
    
    For Each cell In rgStudents.Cells
        If rgOK Is Nothing Then
            IsNotStudentAdded = True
        Else
            MatchOK = Application.Match(cell.Value, rgOK, 0)
            If IsError(MatchOK) Then IsNotStudentAdded = True
        End If
        If IsNotStudentAdded Then
            Student = cell.Value
            For r = 1 To SportsCount
                loOK.ListRows.Add.Range.Resize(, 2).Value _
                     = Array(Student, Sports(r, 1))
            Next r
            IsNotStudentAdded = False
            Set rgOK = lcOK.DataBodyRange
        End If
    Next cell

    MsgBox "Students added.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

So I decided to completely change my macro to avoid any error :

```
Sub Macro7()
Dim N, S, i, j
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
N = Range("Tableau1"): S = Sheets("Sports").Range("C3:C5").Value
With Range("Tableau2").ListObject
  If .ListRows.Count > 0 Then .DataBodyRange.Delete
  For Each i In N
    For Each j In S
      .ListRows.Add.Range.Resize(, 2) = Array(i, j)
    Next
  Next
End With
End Sub
```